# VSCode specific ERROR: EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, administrator

VSCode Python Terminals running in conda environments throw an error message:

`EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.`

All of my other editors (Spyder, PyCharm, JupyterNB, and Anaconda-managed applications) have administrator privileges to execute conda commands.  I don't understand why VSCode is not inheriting the Administrator privileges that I selected for it when I installed it.

I have tried modifying the Windows shortcut for the VSCode executable on the Start Button, but that did not fix it.  I do not want to modify directory permissions or anything else that might have security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to work: Open the folder and right-click on "\Anaconda3". go to properties -> security> choose user and check all the boxes (full control) for each user.

At the same time, granting vscode administrator permissions should also solve the problem.